# Div over GridPanel at select

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I’m not really good in JavaScript and now I’m really stuck. I have an updatepanel on a form. In this updatepanel I have a grid view. When I click over the select button, I want that Panel1 be shown over the table and his corner up-left to be positioned where I clicked.

I've written a function in JavaScript which saves the mouse coordinates into 2 hidden fields:

```
function  getMouseXY(event)
{
    var hiddenFieldX=$get('<%=mouseX.ClientID%>');
    var hiddenFieldY=$get('<%=mouseY.ClientID%>');

    if (navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
        hiddenFieldX.value = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
        hiddenFieldY.value = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
    }
    else
    {
        hiddenFieldX.value=event.pageY
        hiddenFieldY.value=event.pageX
    }
}
```

After, I have to complete into the server side the TextBox1 which is in my Panel1. How can I position the Panel1 where I want? I have the function which sets the coordinates of the panel:

```
function showDetails()
{
    var hiddenFieldX=$get('<%=mouseX.ClientID%>');
    var hiddenFieldY=$get('<%=mouseY.ClientID%>');

    var elem=$get("details") ;
    elem.style.left = hiddenFieldX.value+"px"
    elem.style.top = hiddenFieldY.value+"px"
}
```

but U don't know when I should call it.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="showDetails" Value="false" runat="server" />
         <asp:HiddenField ID="mouseX" Value="0" runat="server" />
         <asp:HiddenField ID="mouseY" Value="0" runat="server" />


         <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" style="border-color:Blue; border-style:double; border-width:thick; width : 200px; height:200px; position:absolute ; top:100px ; left: 100px; z-index:0" Visible="false">
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </asp:Panel>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="EnvoxDataSource" runat="server" </asp:SqlDataSource>
         <asp:GridView ID="gvRecherche" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="30" Caption="Résultats" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="tableSeparator"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="EnvoxDataSource"  
OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvRecherche_SelectedIndexChanged"  
onclick="getMouseXY(event)" >
             <PagerStyle BorderStyle="None"/>
             <HeaderStyle CssClass="tableSeparator" HorizontalAlign="Left"  />
             <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="colorBlanc" />
             <RowStyle CssClass="colorGris" />
             <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#659bed" />
             <Columns>
                 <asp:CommandField InsertVisible="False" SelectImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Standard/images/selectbtn20X20.PNG" SelectText="Select" ShowCancelButton="False" ShowSelectButton="True" ButtonType="Image"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactID" HeaderText="ContactID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ContactID"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeInIVR" HeaderText="TimeInIVR" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TimeInIVR" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TQ" HeaderText="TQ" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TQ"/>
           </Columns>
           <EmptyDataTemplate>
               <div class="message">Aucun résultat pour ces critères</div>
           </EmptyDataTemplate>
           <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="TopAndBottom"         LastPageText="&gt;&gt;" FirstPageText="&lt;&lt;" />
     </asp:GridView> 
     <br />
     <asp:Button ID="btnImprime" runat="server" Text="Version Imprimable" Visible="False" CssClass="bouton" PostBackUrl="<%# GetEnvoxPrintUrl() %>"  target="_blanc" />            
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">showDetails()</script> 
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I think the gv button click will cause a partial postback and that can be intercepted with the javascript below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args)
    {
        showDetails(); // Your javascript
    }
</script>
```